# Indexing a document in Solr without field "id"

Tags: solr, indexing, unique-key, solr4

I have to index a file that doesn't have any field named `key`. I know there is a concept of Unique key in Solr. Can any one help me in the same. I have followed the following steps:-

1. Changing the Unique Key to some other field (say name)
2. Changing required="true" to required="false" for field id

Still I am not able to index a file which doesn't have `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `schema.xml` you can specify which key is unique amongst your documents. [Ref](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Unique_Key_Field)

Also, you may want to read through [this reference](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey), which describes various use cases around Unique Key.

Comment: Thanks .. It worked... the only issue was i was not restarting the Solr.

Comment: Cool - not sure if my answer helped you. If it did, please mark it as answered.